# Preg Match - If string contains character from another string

Tags: php

How can I check whether a string contains any other characters apart from the following?

A-Z 0-9 / \ - _ . ( ) space

Comment: Did you try some thing?

Comment: `preg_match('/[\'^£$%&*()}{@#~?><>,|=_+¬-]/', $string)` Include or exclude character that you want to check.

Comment: /^[a-z A-Z 0-9/\- \ _ \ .\( )\'']+$/

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with the following:

if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9-_.:()/\\ ]+$/", $string)) {